# How to get the value of a loop text field using post method in php

Tags: php, loops

I created all the text field by loop and when I click button of the text field, I can post it to another page. But now I cannot retrieve value of the text field. How can I retrieve the value of the loop text field?

This is my code.

```
<?php 
                $MYSQLQuery1=mysql_query("select id,ccode,pdesc,cost from product2")or die(mysql_error());
                $i=1;
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($MYSQLQuery1)){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo"<img src='img/".$row['ccode'].".jpg' width='150' height='200'/>","<br/>"; 
                              echo $row['pdesc'],"<br/>"; 
                              echo $row['cost']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='product".$i."'>";  ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="addvehicle.php" role="form" method="POST" class="form-inline">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                            <input type="submit" name="SUBMITEDITVEHICLE"  value="Edit" class="btn btn-success">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>
```

This is where I post the value.

```
if(isset($_POST['SUBMITEDITVEHICLE']))
{
    if($_POST['SUBMITEDITVEHICLE']=='Edit')
    {   
            $i=0;
            $E_1 = clean($_POST['ID']);
            $gt = clean($_POST['product. $i']); 
            echo $gt,"<br/>";
            $query_editvehicle=mysql_query("SELECT ccode,pdesc,cost FROM product2 WHERE ID='$E_1' ")or die(mysql_error());
            while($roweditvehicle=mysql_fetch_array($query_editvehicle))
            {
                $txtid = $roweditvehicle['id'];
                $txtvehicleregno = $roweditvehicle['ccode'];
                $txtmakemodel = $roweditvehicle['pdesc'];
                $txtcost = $roweditvehicle['cost']; 
            }
        echo txtvehivleregno;
        echo txtmakemodel;
        echo txtcost;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `<td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='product".$i."'>"; // ?></td>`

Its a text box right, so you have to assign the value by

```
<td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='product".$i."' value=$row['cost']>"; // ?></td>
```

Comment: when I click the button, the value of the textbox post to another page, but now I can't get the value when I click the edit button

Comment: you can get it by the name of your text box. `name='product".$i."`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can echo it inside the while like this:

```
<input type='text' name='product[]'> //don't forget the []
```

then it if you post it you can have an array value,

```
$products = $_POST['product'];
print_r($products);//to print array
```

try this code:

```
<?php 
            $MYSQLQuery1=mysql_query("select id,ccode,pdesc,cost from product2")or die(mysql_error());
            $i=1;
            echo '<form action="addvehicle.php" role="form" method="POST" class="form-inline">';
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($MYSQLQuery1))
              {
                echo "
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <img src='img/".$row['ccode'].".jpg' width='150' height='200'/>
                           <br/>
                          ".$row['pdesc']."<br/>"
                           .$row['cost']. 
                      "</td>
                        <td>
                          <input type='text' name='product[]'>
                       </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='submit' name='SUBMITEDITVEHICLE'  value='Edit' class='btn btn-success'>

                     </td>
                    </tr>"; //end of one echo and end of tr
               }//end of while

 echo "</form>"; //end of form
            ?>
```

Comment: forgot to mention that you should put the inputs inside the form before you  submit it. 
`<form>
//while loop for 
<input type='text' name='product[]'> //don't forget the []
//other elements like the button here
</form>`
As I can see in your code it is outside of the form

Comment: I put everything inside the form now, but still not working

Comment: I tried that but when I click the button, I only getting the last value

Comment: `$_POST['product'];` have you removed the `$i` at your post? because I tried it and it is giving me an array.

Comment: I edited your code in php like [this](http://prntscr.com/ft25zq) and for the [post here](http://prntscr.com/ft267w) and it is giving me something [like this](http://prntscr.com/ft26ra) and the result is [this](http://prntscr.com/ft26vm)

Comment: I tried your code. And [this](https://prnt.sc/ftongd) is my code and [this](https://prnt.sc/ftoowr) where I post. And when I click edit button of product id 5 in [here](https://prnt.sc/ftoq68), the result is [this](https://prnt.sc/ftoqb2). I'm getting the last product.